# function IF but in French

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to code a function named SI, which works as if (SI is the French word for if), but with this syntax :

```
SI(condition)
ALORS{
function hello()
}
SINON{
function bye();
function goodbye();
}
```

In Javascript it would be:

```
if(condition){
    function hello();
}
else{
function bye();
function goodbye();
}
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write JavaScript in Other Languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839966/write-javascript-in-other-languages)

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840610/overwriting-javascript-keywords

Comment: The truth is that you cannot achieve what you need exactly by using Javascript. The benefits will always be by far less than the loses in time and money to build it. You can build a french/javascript compiler that is based on javascript syntax but this would take a considerable amount of time and effort.

Comment: the objective is to have simple instructions for my students to make short programs (for now, drawing with a simple Turtle), the javascript syntax is a bit too difficult for them, and it is in English...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
function si(condition) {
    return {
        alors: function(callback) {
            if (condition) callback();
            return this;
        },
        sinon: function(callback) {
            if (!condition) callback();
            return this;
        }
    };
}

var x = 0;

si(x == 1)
  .alors(() => console.log("Bonjour!"))
  .sinon(() => console.log("Au revoir!"));
```

How does this work?

- `si` is a function that returns an object
- That object has two functions, `alors` and `sinon`
- `alors` is a function that takes another function `callback` as argument, if `condition` (which has been passed to `si`) is true then `alors` will execute the callback function
- `() => console.log(...)` is a short-hand notation for `function() { return console.log(...); }` which creates an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks ! It works very well, and it is possible to have several functions to run

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your answer to a REPETER function :

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your answer to a REPETER function :
'code'
function REPETER() {
 return {
  NOMBRE_DE_FOIS: nb
  ,
  INSTRUCTIONS: function(callback) {
   for(i_repeter=1;i_repeter<=nb;i_repeter++) callback();
   return this ;
  }
 };
}
'code'
but I have a problem with NOMBRE_DE_FOIS (that is not a function).

Comment: Pass `nb` as a parameter to the `REPETER` function, `function REPETER(nb) { return ...`

Comment: It seems that two instructions REPETER doesn't work
    var xxx = 1 ;
    REPETER(2)
    .INSTRUCTIONS( () => {
    xxx = xxx + 1 ;
    REPETER(5)
    .INSTRUCTIONS( () => {
    xxx = xxx + 2 ;
    alert(xxx);
   });
   });

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:Nope, you cannot override js basics. But you can emulate a certain behavior:

```
function si(condition,alors,sinon){
  if(condition){
   alors();
  }else{
   sinon();
 }
 }
```

Use like this:

```
si(a==true,
 //alors
 function(){
  alert("a");
 },
 //sinon
 function(){
 alert("no a");
 });
```

Or:

```
function evaluate(obj){
 if(obj.si){
   obj.alors();
 }else{
   obj.sinon();
 };
```

Use like this:

```
evaluate({
si:a==true,
alors:function(){},
sinon:function(){}
});
```

You could also compile a string to native js, that would have exactly your syntax:

```
function frenchjs(string){
var translate={
si:"if",
sinone:"else"
};
for(key in translate){
string=string.replace(key,translate[key]);
}
eval(string);
}
```

Use like this:

```
frenchjs("si(a==true){alert('a')}sinnon{alert('no a');}");
```